# How to use CreateNativeQuery to query single value from SQL database value?

Tags: java, sql, database, nativequery

using a CRUD and want o access a certain value in the databse. what I tried is:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select o from Table o where o.IDfield= '938'"); 
Table o = (Table)query.getSingleResult();
```

but this fails.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your select looks like a jpql query so it won't work when passed directly to the database as a native query. You can use the `createQuery` method instead. Even better would be to use a named parameterized query declared on your entity like this:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name="MyEntity.findById", query="select o from MyEntity o where o.IDfield = :id"})
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private String IDfield;
}

...

MyEntity entity = (MyEntity)em.createNamedQuery("MyEntity.findById").setParameter("id", "938").getSingleResult();
```

Comment: And also thanks, I didn't know how to set the parameter in the named query.
It take it using namedQuery being preferential is just a matter tidiness and re-usability?

Comment: Jan Gvdp: Another reason for named queries is that they get syntax checked at deploy time, so you might find typos easier. Also there should be a small performance improvement since the query is only translated to sql once.